# Minecraft Pi keyboard issues

Tags: minecraft

I recently set up a new RPi 4 for my son, using the latest Raspberry Pi OS with desktop and recommended softwares.
Everything seems to work fine except Minecraft Pi.
The problem is that some keys from the keyboard are not handled:

- i can jump (space), exit (esc) but that's it
- mouse control is ok

Using python to perform actions works.

I don't know where to look, i already removed and re installed the `minecraft-pi` package through `apt`.

The only source of trouble could be from the keyboard setup: I have 2 languages set (he-IL/en-US).

If someone has already encountered/fixed  this problem or has any idea, I will be grateful.

Thanks